# A-Frame Animation-mixer start animation at a perticular time frame

Tags: animation, aframe

How can I start an animation from the middle of it (from nth time/frame) in a-frame animation mixer

Answer (score 0):

[Soon](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/pull/337) the animation mixer will have a `startFrame` attribute which will determine the start time in miliseconds.

---

There is an easy way to implement it though. The component is based on the [THREE.AnimationMixer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer) which is available as a `animation-mixer` property:

```
// element refers to an entity with the animation mixer; make sure it's loaded
let mixerComponent = element.components["animation-mixer"]
let mixer = mixerComponent.mixer;
```

The mixer has a `setTime(time)` function which will set the animation start at the given time (in seconds):

```
// will set the start time at 1s
mixer.setTime(1);
```

If the animation is looped, be sure to do so on each loop:

```
this.el.addEventListener("animation-loop", e => mixer.setTime(1));
```

You can see it working [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/models/animation_mixer_starttime.html) ([source](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/models/animation_mixer_starttime.html))